# AJAX 400 Bad Request Worpress PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm currently using a GraphQL API with Ajax & PHP on Worpress.

First things first, everything is working as well as expected on my browser/account. But as soon as I change my google user or different browser or going on my phone. My ajax request get a 400 from my admin-ajax.php.

Honestly, I have no idea what is the problem, I'm just doing a simple request on php with ajax, then I make a GraphQL query in my back, then I send it back in JSON format in my front. That's all.
I have 400 bad request w/e I try to do in my back. I have no clue what to do neither where to look for.

This is one of my ajax request.

ajaxurl is defined no worries:)

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,

    data: {
      'action': 'get_content_wino'
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log("fetch ok")
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

This is my back.

```
function get_content_wino()
{
   if ( isset($_REQUEST) )
   {
       echo read_file();
       die();
   }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_content_wino' , 'get_content_wino' );
```

w/e my action is I get 400. on admin-ajax.php

Quick reminder, everything is perfectly working as long as I have the same browser and google accounts. There is no ip whitelist or login account on my website, pure ajax and php here.

Thanks

Comment: Add an additional action hook underneath your `wp_ajax_get_content_wino` action hook. Like this: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_content_wino' , 'get_content_wino' );`. [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/)

Comment: FIrst how is this a thing. Second you are absolutely gorgeous and right thanks alot mate !

Comment: To add to @Ruvee comment - the _nopriv_ ensures the action can be called without login privileges. This is likely why when you try to make the Ajax call and run the action it is preventing you from doing so. Generally, for any actions you intend to have run by users who are not logged in, you need to add this. If you're building ajax functions that will only be run while logged in, it's not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two action hooks when you hook into `wp_ajax`.

- `wp_ajax_{$action}` for for logged-in users. [Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/)

and

- `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` for logged-out users. [Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/)

So to combine the two, you could use the following code:

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_content_wino' , 'get_content_wino' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_content_wino' , 'get_content_wino' );

function get_content_wino()
{
   if ( isset($_REQUEST) )
   {
       echo read_file();
       die();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, but I litteraly have the same issue again, but with js code only, I have button and event listener on them when I click, it's working perfectly with my account, but when I go on another browser, device or account, it's not working anymore too, do you have any idea ?

Comment: That could be for several reasons. I'll try to help you debug it but in order to do so, please provide more details. For example when you say you "have the same issue with js code only", what does that mean? Do you get any error in the browser's console? If so, then please provide the error message from your js code and also provide some screenshots, if possible. Also make sure that you're requesting to `admin-ajax.php`. I could help you only if I could see your code in details.